# iOS App Store search url scheme

Tags: ios, search, app-store

I am looking for a way to open the App Store app on iOS and search for a query term from a URL.

The closest I have gotten so far is getting the app open and query field filled, but the query is filled incorrectly. Instead of being filled with `virtual reality`, the search box gets filled with `( "virtual reality" )`, and the app says no results. The URL works to open iTunes with a search for `virtual reality`.
https://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=virtual%20reality

*I am **not** looking for the JSON Search API* and all URLs I have found do not work anymore (most links I found claiming to do this mention iOS 6 or are at least a year old).

Not working:

- http ://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=SEARCH_TERMS
- https ://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&q=virtual%20reality&mt=12 (opens Mac App Store on OS X, iTunes Store app on iOS)
- https ://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/advancedSearch?entity=software&term=virtual+reality&submit=seeAllLockups (opens correct search results on OS X iTunes but opens iTunes Store app on iOS)

Is there a way to open the App Store and search for a query from a URL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use "itms-apps://" url scheme to open the App Store app on iOS directly:

So the example for your use case is:

itms-apps://search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=virtual+reality

Easiest way to test this is with a Mac and the Notes app with iCloud sync.

[image]

Comment: Just checked. It still has ("") around the search term.